# Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'presentViewController' in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, skscene

I'm trying to present a menu (GameViewController). I try to execute this move in GameScene:

```
let secondViewController:GameViewController = GameViewController()

self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but there's an error on the `self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)` line it says "Value of type 'GameScene' has no member 'presentViewController' in Swift". I can't execute the move using .presentViewController , it needs to be done programmatically and without using segues and it has to be able to be used in a SKScene.

Thanks in advance,
Niall

Comment: You need to call `presentViewController` from a `UIViewController`. `GameScene` isn't a view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, but how would I call this?

Comment: @rmaddy I get a print out  Attempt to present <Cube_Falling.GameViewController: 0x796c3c20> on <UIViewController: 0x796c4100> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
 When I try this:                                                                                                 let secondViewController:GameViewController = GameViewController()
                var viewh = UIViewController()
                
                viewh.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: You have to get a reference to an existing view controller that is already being shown. You can't just create a new one and present from that.

Comment: @rmaddy How should I reference this in the code?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple,  every different scene or screen in a game should be presented with a different `SKScene` object.

A single `GameViewContoller` and a single `SKView` can be used to present a lot of different scenes like the main menu and the levels in a game.

For example from inside a `SKScene` class reference the `SKView` using `self.view` and tell it to present your main menu `SKScene`.